# Pid-dependent Global Configuration Values?

Tags: email, configuration, typo3

Before calling `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::send` on a `MailMessage`, the record gets persisted in one of the two Email record storage pages that I have.
Then the Email gets sent by calling that method. For this, the global configuration values described in [Mail API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html) are used.

The thing is that I want some of these values to be different depending on the Pid of the email record being sent. What would be the most sensible way to achieve that? The only way I can think of doing this right now would be to extend and override the aforementioned class and method, and changing the desired `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL'][...]` values before the `parent::send` call. But I'm not sure if this would be the most sensible and optimal way of achieving this. Should I try something else?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question still leaves a lot of additional questions:
what version of TYPO3 are you using?
what plugin do you use to transform information (User input?) into a mail?

depending on the software you have options to configure the mails additional to the basic configuration from `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']`.
This configuration is stored in `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`, which just stores constant data. But you also have `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` where you can use functions to set values dynamically.

Probably the best way would be to configure your plugin with typoscript or fields in the CE to behave different depending on the page you work.

e.g.: if you use `ext:form` you have **finisher** you can configure to set parameters for mails, depending on any available information.